# How to call an iValueConverter from code behind?

Tags: windows-phone-7, data-binding

I have a class `MinutesToHourMinutesConverter : IValueConverter` that converts the numbers of minutes in `HH:mm` format and it runs fine in data binding.

To avoid to repeat code I would like to reuse it in other parts of the code, how can I do it?

Answer (score 6):

```
 new MinutesToHourMinutesConverter().Convert(...)
```